# $28 + p \sqrt{3} = (q + 2 \sqrt{3})^2$, where p and q are integers, find the values of p and of q.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is how much I have solved so far,

> $$28 + p \sqrt{3} = (q + 2 \sqrt{3})^2$$
>
> $$ \implies28 + p \sqrt{3} = q^2 + (4 \sqrt{3})q + 12$$
>
> $$\implies p \sqrt{3} = q^2 + (4 \sqrt{3})q - 16$$
>
> $$\implies p = (q^2 + (4 \sqrt{3})q - 16)/(\sqrt{3})$$

which gives $p$ as ${-8.755604237, 1.827401007}$

But since $p$ is supposed to be an integer (and $q$) this would be the wrong answer to my question.

How could the answers be in such a way that $p$ and $q$ are integers?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Start by expanding $(q+2\sqrt3)^2$ to the form $a+b\sqrt3$; then solve $a=28$ and $b=p$

Comment: I.e., $q^2-16=0$ and $p=4q$

Comment: Try grouping the rational and irrational terms, and then equate them separately.

Comment: The numbers you gave are solutions to $q^2+4\sqrt3q-16=0$, but they're not solutions to the question

Comment: +1 This is actually a good question. Unfortunately there have been many instances of new users asking bad questions, so some users might be reluctant to upvote. If you can keep this up and ask more good questions, you will probably get more upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it.

$28 + p\sqrt{3}=(q+2\sqrt 3)^2 = q^2 +4q\sqrt 3 + 12$

$16 - q^2  = \sqrt 3(4q - p)$.

$16-q^2$ is an integer.  So is $4q -p$.  So $\sqrt 3\times (4q-p)$ is an integer.

Let $\sqrt 3(4q-p) = M$ then our first thought is $\sqrt 3 = \frac M{4q-p}$.  But thats impossible as $\sqrt 3$ is irrational.

The only way this makes sense is if $4q - p = 0$ so $p=4q$.

So $16 -q^2 = \sqrt 3(4q -p) = 0$ so $q^2 = 16$ and $q = \pm 4$ and $p = \pm 16$.

Answer (score 1):

You got essentially $0+p\sqrt3=(q^2-16)+4q\sqrt3.$  Solve $q^2-16=0$ and $p=4q$ and you're done.

> $(q,p)=\pm(4,16)$